# Cpuminer problem: empty reply from server

Tags: miner-configuration, getwork, minerd

When I run the following command:

```
minerd.exe -o http://eu-stratum.btcguild.com:3333 -u username_1 -p password -a sha256d -R 2
```

I get this:

```
2 miner threads started, using 'sha256d' algorithm.
Binding thread 0 to cpu 0
Binding thread 1 to cpu 1
HTTP request failed: Empty reply from server
json_rpc_call failed, retry after 2 seconds
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The miner you are using does not support the [stratum protocol](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Stratum). Instead you must use a pool that uses the old and now obsolete [getwork protocol](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getwork)

If I see it correctly BTCGuild still offers the getwork access with the following URL:

```
minerd.exe -o http://btcguild.com:8332 -u username_1 -p password -a sha256d -R 2
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now.
I'm new to bitcoin, didn't know anything about protocols.
I was just curious, but my CPU only can produce 7MH/s, and as I know that's not much.

Comment: Unfortunately, BTCGuild is closing down.